# Ionic 2: Pass param to next page as copy, not by reference

Tags: typescript, copy, angular, ionic2, object-reference

**Q) How do I pass my param to the next page as a copy, so that changes to it don't persist in the previous screen when I go back?**

e.g.

```
  showDetails(item) {
    this._nav.push(PersonDetailsPage, {
      person: item
    });    
  }
```

So when I view the PersonDetailsPage, I want to be able to make changes, cancel, go back and not have the original object modified.

Thanks.

Comment: Clone the object and pass the clone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now I've gone with:

```
var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use "Object.assign"

```
let original = { person: items };
let copy = Object.assign({}, original );
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, objects are passed by reference.  Only primatives (number, string, boolean, etc) are passed by value.  Your best bet is going to be using the Object.assign method to make a copy of the object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately it doesn't copy nested objects so it's busted.